# Add blank image in current running apps windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

For security, i want to hide the information displayed when user clicks on Windows key or search key... (Alternative show a black screen)

Any action(Visibility, etc) on the UI elements called in deactivation event do not fire unless the app is reactivated.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In `App.xaml`, add a handler for the `Deactivated` event. That is called whenever your app goes to background.

```
<!-- App.xaml -->
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" ...>
    <Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
        <shell:PhoneApplicationService Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
    </Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
</Application>

// App.xaml.cs
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Your app is going to background
}
```